# Mysql Error in simple query

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc

For this query I am getting error

```
"INSERT INTO table " 
  + "(item1,item2) "
  + "VALUES "
  + "(" + number1 + "," + number2 + ");"
```

The error says

> Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'item1,item2) VALUES (10,1)' at line 1

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you used **table** as the tablename? show us the real sql that produced by your code will be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (item1,item2) VALUES (" + 
    number1 + "," + number2 + ");"
```

`Table` is a MySql reserved word, so you should enclose it in backticks.
Check other reserved words [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: @koool: glad to help you! Just a suggestion: to avoid headaches, in future try to avoid using reserved words for table and column names! :)